Calculus Made Easy Chapter 9 Example 1 p.(100)

If $z = 3x^4$, $v = 7/z^2$, $y = (1+v)^{1/2}$, find $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

The final answer comes to $-28/3x^5(9x^8 + 7)^{1/2}$, however, I can only obtain something similar: $-28/9x^9(9x^8 + 7)^{1/2}$.
What am I missing?  How is the denominator starting with $3x^5$ while I'm coming to $9x^9$.  Any help is appreciated.

you can learn to format mathematical expressions on this site by reading this guide.

Using chain rule.
$$ \dfrac{dy}{dx}=-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{dv}{dx}(1-v)^{-1/2} $$
$$\dfrac{dv}{dx}=-\dfrac{dz}{dx}\dfrac{14}{z^3}=-\dfrac{dz}{dx}\dfrac{14}{27x^{12}} $$
$$ \dfrac{dz}{dx}=12x^3 $$
Can you verify your result from here or you need more steps ?

Hi EDX, could you show me the steps on how came to 9x^12 as the denominator?  When substituting 3x^4 in for z within dv/dx, I would assume it would equal 14/(3x^4)^3.  Am I on the right path or way off?

Sorry I correct it is 27

Thats great, EDX, because I'm receiving the same results.  However, when I put it all together, my final result is NOT 3x^5(9x^8+7)^1/2 for the denominator, which is what the book says is the correct answer

Just simply take $$v=\frac{7}{9x^{8}}\implies \frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{7}{9}(-8)x^{-9}$$
So $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d(1+v)^{\frac12}}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+v}}\frac{dv}{dx}\\\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-28x^{-5}}{3\sqrt{7+9x^{8}}}$$
I sadly can't rectify you unless you mention what method you used

Hi Gwen, I trying to use the chain rule.

The author obtains this before simplifying even further to the final answer $-\frac {168x^3}{2(z^3)\sqrt {1+v}}$..   I'm able to obtain that, however, i'm having troubles getting to the final: -  $\frac {28}{3x^5 \sqrt {9x^8+7}}$
